# Sentencias preparadas, buscador

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statements

como puedo hacer una sentencia preparada con la variable **$busqueda** , donde irian los **%%**??

```
SELECT * FROM productadm  WHERE name like '%$busqueda%' AND ...
```

Por ejemplo mis otras sentencias preparadas, también de mysqli **NO PDO**(como en la etiqueta)  van asi:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  cat = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT $start_f,$porpag");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $categorian);
 $stmt->execute();
 $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Debes indicar primero que API estás usando, si PDO o mysqli y mostrar tu consulta preparada con sus marcadores, pues en PDO mismo hay dos formas distintas de marcar los parámetros y de pasarlos. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega un EMV (Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable).

Answer (score 2):

La consultas preparadas usan un marcador, en este caso, tu marcador es `?` . Simplemente ese marcador dice al manejador: *en ese lugar va un dato, el cual te pasaré luego, con el método adecuado para eso, para que un hacker no te engañe*.

Entendido eso, en el caso de `LIKE` simplemente preparas tu criterio de filtro tal cual, agregando los delimitadores a la variable que pasarías en parámetro. El método de la API se encargará de verificar cualquier anomalía en esos datos.

El código quedaría así:

```
 $mParam="%$categorian%"; #Aunque un hacker intente manipular lo que llega
                          #en la variable $categorian, no hay riesgo aquí
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  name LIKE ? ORDER BY id LIMIT $start_f,$porpag");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $mParam);
 $stmt->execute();
 $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
```

---

Podemos ver un ejemplo con dos `LIKE` que usarían el **dos parámetros, pero con el mismo valor**:

```
 $mParam="%$categorian%";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  name LIKE ? OR apellido LIKE ? ORDER BY id LIMIT $start_f,$porpag");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $mParam, $mParam);
 $stmt->execute();
 $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
```

Si analizas este código en `bind_param()` pasas dos veces la misma variable, porque se usará el mismo dato como criterio para filtrar .

---

O bien uno que usa dos `LIKE`  con **dos parámetros con dos valores individuales**:

```
 $pName="%$mName%";
 $pLastName="%mLastName%";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE  name LIKE ? OR apellido LIKE ? ORDER BY id LIMIT $start_f,$porpag");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $pName, $pLastName);
 $stmt->execute();
 $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
```

En todos los casos, lo que haces en `bind_param()` es decirle al manejador: *aquí están los datos que te prometí (en los marcadores de la consulta preparada), chequea que el usuario no ha hecho trampa con ellos, intentando inyectar código malicioso.* Queda claro que debes pasar cada valor correspondiente en el orden respectivo. Eso está explicado en la documentación.

### Advertencia

En tu consulta, en la parte del `LIMIT`, se aprecian otras dos variables que no sé de donde vienen, tampoco están en el contexto de tu pregunta original. Debes saber que si esas dos variables están al alcance del usuario, deberían también ser pasadas con `bind_param()`, pues el *quid* de la cuestión aquí es evitar que el usuario manipule cualquier variable para inyectar código malicioso, y el punto de entrada para hacer eso son precisamente los datos que éste proporciona y que luego tú asumes en el código.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han dicho hay 2 formas de realizar lo que dices, para el caso de `PDO` asumamos que ya tienes tu conexion con la base de datos creada y almacenada, entonces lo que deberas hacer es:

```
//Con placeholders
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE name LIKE :name AND x LIKE :x");

//Una vez guardada la consulta, se debe ejecutar pasandole la siguiente informacion:
$query->execute(
    [
        ":name" => "%busqueda%",    //Debe coincidir con el oden y nombre de los placeholders
        ":x"    => "%algun contenido%"
    ]
)

//Obtiene la informacion generada por la consulta
$resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

La segunda forma es usar el caracter `?` como reemplazo, hagamos el ejemplo con la misma busqueda:

```
//Con ?
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productadm WHERE name LIKE ? AND x LIKE ?");

//Una vez guardada la consulta, se debe ejecutar pasandole la siguiente informacion:
$query->execute(["%busqueda%", "%algun contenido%"])

//Obtiene la informacion generada por la consulta
$resultado = $query->fetchAll();
```

Ambos generan un resultado parecido, la diferencia es que con el primero usas `arreglos asociativos` para generar claves al momento de usar `json_encode` mientras que en el segundo las claves se dan de forma numerica (por medio de indices numericos).

Comment: El OP usa mysqli

Comment: @BetaM es cierto, el usuario usa mysqli, sin embargo jamas he usado mysqli asi que no sabria realmente adaptar esta respuesta, de igual forma puede serle útil a alguna otra persona que este usando PDO, dejare igual la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien mas.